# simple typescript class not running

Tags: typescript

I have written Customer class.Its compiling fine but when I run this its saying

firstName: string;

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
?[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)?[39m
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47?[39m
```

```
class Customer {
    
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
    
        constructor(theFirst: string, theLast: string) {
            this.firstName = theFirst;
            this.lastName = theLast;
        }
    }
    
    // let's create an instance
    let myCustomer = new Customer("Martin", "Dixon");
    
    console.log(myCustomer.firstName);
    console.log(myCustomer.lastName);
```

Comment: Share your tsconfig and your node version.

Comment: Maybe configuration issue. otherwise, code is running fine here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: I am running example in visual studio.Where this tsconfig.json is located?.node version is V12.18.3

Comment: It sounds like you're running the TypeScript code instead of the compiled JavaScript output. That are indicates that note is trying to execute file containing a type annotation

Comment: Open a command prompt in the directory containing the typescript file that has your class in it and then run the following commands `npm i -g typescript`, `tsc myclass.ts`, and  finally `node myclass.js`

Comment: my bad yes you are correct .I am running TypeScript code instead of the compiled JavaScript output. Thanks for pointing.